# When I try to request the data, its return none. How can i fix it?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying beautifulsoup library of python for develop myself and I realized I had to get help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
data = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"row_summable sortable stats_table now_sortable"})
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The html you download is not exactly the same as the html displayed on the webpage. At a certain point whilst loading the webpage, javascript adds the `now_sortable` class to the table in your browser.

When you download the page using requests, this bit of javascript is never performed, and therefore you don't have the `now_sortable` class in your table, and that's why you can't find the element.

Try changing your code to:

```
data = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"row_summable sortable stats_table"})
```

A general tip: when downloading a file using requests, try saving the page you've requested locally so you can have a proper look into it:

```
with open('local_page.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    fout.write(r.text)
```

Comment: I literally was just about to post the same thing. Beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Selenium to render the page and then pull the html:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
data = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"row_summable sortable stats_table now_sortable"})
print(data)
```